# MAUIのCollectionViewで、選択時に項目の見た目を変えたい

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

MAUIのCollectionViewで、選択時に項目の見た目を変えたいです。[公式のドキュメント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/selection?source=recommendations)で選択項目の色を変える例が示されていますが、この方法による変化は限定的で、もっと自由に、DataTemplateの中身を変更したいと思っています。現在このようなCollectionViewを例に調べています。

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionView" SelectionMode="Single" Background="lightgray" SelectionChanged="collectionView_SelectionChanged" local:IsSelectedBehavior.IsSelected="True">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="16,0,0,0"/>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="2">
                    <Rectangle.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Name="rectangle">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="red"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Rectangle" Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="green"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Rectangle.Style>
                </Rectangle>
                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

ItemsSourceはコードビハインドから入れています。コレクションのアイテムクラスにIsSelectedプロパティが定義されており、TapGestureRecognizer_Tappedで、ItemsSourceのオブジェクトにアクセスしてこのプロパティを変更することで、各項目が選択されていることを認識できるようにしています。このコードで、選択時にRectangleの色を替える、ということは実現しています。

**これと同じことを、View単体で完結させたいです。アイテムクラスにIsSelectedプロパティを定義したくありません。**

これを実現するため、以下のことを試しました。
・添付プロパティを自作して、IsSelectedの代わりに使う
　これは、プロパティを設定するところと、添付プロパティにバインディングするところで躓きました。自作した添付プロパティはCollectionのItemコントロールに設定しなければならないと思いましたが、CollectionViewはWPFで言う所のItemContainerGeneratorを公開していないため、子のコントロールを取得できませんでした。また添付プロパティのバインディングに関しては、そもそもバインドが全く機能しませんでした。MAUIでは添付プロパティに対するバインディングはできませんか？

・VisualStateManagerを使う
　DataTemplate直下のGridコントロールにVSMを定義し、ここから[このリンクの方法で](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager)、Rectangleの見た目を変えようとしました。しかし選択した瞬間に例外が発生し、うまく切り替わりませんでした。どこで何の例外が発生したのか、デバッガで確認できませんでした。

VisualStudio 17.3.0 Preview 6.0を使用しています。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [正式版の17.3.3](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#1733--visual-studio-2022-version-1733)または[17.4 Preview 1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview#1740-pre10--visual-studio-2022-version-174-preview-1)に更新して試してみてはどうでしょう？ あるいはXamarinでは出来ているとかなら、こちらの [Migrating from Xamarin.Forms (Preview)](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Migrating-from-Xamarin.Forms-(Preview))・[FAQs](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/faqs)・[Roadmap](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Roadmap)を探してみるとか？

Comment: こうした記事 [What's Next for .NET MAUI? Roadmap & Xamarin Sunset Unveiled](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2022/08/22/net-maui-roadmap.aspx) で2024/5月くらいまでXamarinをサポートしてその間に互換性や機能を向上させるらしいので、[Issues](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues)を調べたり自分で要望を出すとかしてみても良いのでは？